# csv update database table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, csv

Currently i have a csv file that populates a table. I'm wanitng ot schedule this so it runs daily. However rather than wipe the table, Could it be possible to have it so it only adds what doesn't yet exist?

Lets say i have this layout at the moment.

```
Title|Name|Date|Url|
1    |2   |3   |4  |
```

Then my CSV has this inside it

```
Title|Name|Date|Url|
1    |2   |3   |4  |
1    |2   |3   |7  |
```

Would it be possible to ignore the first row of the csv and add the second one as the url column field is different?

Heres what i have so far

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
namespace :event do
   task reload: :environment do
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE events RESTART IDENTITY")
       gzipped = open('URL LINK HERE')
       csv_text = Zlib::GzipReader.new(gzipped).read
       csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
       csv.each do |row|
         Event.create(time: row[9], date: row[10], URL: row[8], eventname: row[7])

       end
   end
end
```

I know that obviously i'll be looking at removing this lie and chanign it to an update of some sort?

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE events RESTART IDENTITY")
```

Also i'm using rails if it helps at all?

Comment: you'd have to keep track of where you left off in the csv file. e.g. save the byte offset/file pointer location, then `seek()` there each time.

Comment: The CSV is constantly moving around, It'd have to be scanned everytime, The only thing that stays the same are the headers and the urls are the unique things.

Comment: then probably the easiest thing is to load the entire csv into a temp table, then merge this temp table with the "real" table, so only the new records get added.

Comment: I thought about this, Wouldnt it slow down the database? Or rails? Or potentially cause a memory leak? I alos have no idea how i could go about this

Comment: just how big is this csv file? because if you have to scan the entire thing to try and figure out what's new (which would require selecting everything in the db ANYWAYS), a simple bulk-load to temp table, merge, then dump temp table, will probably be MORE efficient than "read row, check if in db, insert if not, repeat ad nauseum". one `load data infile` query, one `insert ... select from`, done - 2 queries v.s. `read csv line, select from db, insert into db` for EVERY line in the csv.

Comment: its uhm, 24k ish rows with about 18 headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find_or_create_by`, like this:

```
Event.find_or_create_by(time: row[9], date: row[10], URL: row[8], eventname: row[7])
```

That will only create a new row unless it finds a match on all 4 fields.

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by

Comment: Hey, I just need to remove this line right?, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE events RESTART IDENTITY")`

Comment: @SamAdmit oh yes, you wouldn't need that line anymore.

Comment: Briliant! Worked a treat